# Can we say an achievement "is" a title for someone?

Tags: meaning

> All scientific progress consists in the advance from a less to a more adequate hypothesis. The Greeks were the first to follow this method, and that **is** their title to be regarded as the originators of science. (John Burnet, Early Greek Philosophy)

I think the author means that the Greek way of doing science earn the title for Greeks. But I do not know why he uses the link verb "is". Is it a figure of speech?

Comment: The author uses the word title in the sense of 'ownership': *I hold the title to this property.* This is general reference.

Answer (score 1):

The author wrote this thought in a VERY awkward way.

He could have simply said:

> The Greeks were the first to follow this method, and they have earned
>   the title "originators of science"

Or

> The Greeks did it first; they invented science.

Comment: In light of what you said, I will try: The Greeks were the first to follow this method, and this entitles them to be regarded as the originators of science.

Answer (score 1):

Burnet was writing in 1920, meaning that perhaps Ace Frahm's claim 'The author wrote this thought in a very awkward way.' is unjustified. It is certainly parochial.

At AHD, there is a sense of 'title' given that is still apparently considered viable - though the fact that Collins doesn't list it is significant:

> **title** . . .
>
> 8a. Something that provides a basis for or justifies a claim.

Thus  'that is their title to be regarded as the originators of science' may be paraphrased 'that is why they are entitled to be regarded as the originators of science' - though here, I *would* prefer Ace's not-quite-paraphrase.